# Update mongodb document using discriminators

Tags: mongodb, express, mongoose

I've got a question about discriminators and mongoose/mongodb. I would like to understand how I can update one document which contains 2 properties whichs are array of discriminators.

Here my mongoose models :

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const carSchema = require('./car');
const continentalWheelSchema = require('./wheel/continental');
const michelinWheelSchema = require('./wheel/michelin');

const CarSchema = new mongoose.Schema({}, { discriminatorKey: 'type', _id: false } );
const WheelSchema = new mongoose.Schema({}, { discriminatorKey: 'type', _id: false } );

const ClientParkSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    customer: { type: String, required: true },
    created_at: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
    updated_at: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
    cars: [CarSchema],
    wheels: [WheelSchema]
});

ClientParkSchema.path('cars').discriminator('break', carSchema);
ClientParkSchema.path('wheels').discriminator('continental', continentalWheelSchema);
ClientParkSchema.path('wheels').discriminator('michelin', michelinWheelSchema);

module.exports = {
    ClientPark: mongoose.model('client_park', ClientParkSchema, 'client_park')
};

/////////////////////// CAR SCHEMA ////////////////////////

const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const CarSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    brand: { type: String, required: true },
    model: { type: String, required: true },
}, { _id: false } );

module.exports = CarSchema;

/////////////////////// CONTINENTAL WHEEL SCHEMA ////////////////////////

const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const ContinentalWheelSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    model: { type: String, required: true }
}, { _id: false } );

module.exports = ContinentalWheelSchema;

/////////////////////// MICHELIN WHEEL SCHEMA ////////////////////////

const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const MichelinWheelSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    price: { type: number, required: true},
    model: { type: String, required: true },
    season: { type: String, required: true }
}, { _id: false } );

module.exports = MichelinWheelSchema;
```

mongodb query :

```
db.client_park.updateOne({_id: ObjectId('5d3865a4e56473518adabd35'), "car.type": 'break',"wheel.type": "michelin"}, {$set: {"car.$.brand": 'Ford',"wheel.$.price": 100,"wheel.$.season": "summer"}})
```

The query seems to work but the document is not updated. So I would like to know how could I update my document by discriminators (if there are exists).

Thank you very much !

EDIT :

The document I want to update :

```
{  
   "_id":"5d39a19e2376c7089ec7707b",
   "customer":"5d0757aa4b6620003335aff2",
   "cars":[  
      {  
         "type":"break",
         "brand":"Ford"
      }
   ],
   "created_at":"2019-07-25T12:33:34.799Z",
   "updated_at":"2019-07-25T12:33:34.799Z",
   "_v":0
}
```

Comment: can you post the full document (or at least the values you are querying for and want to update) ?

Comment: Also, just to make sure, '$' will only update the first occurence of the object you are querying for.

Comment: @BenSower I updated the question. Wheel discriminator doesn't exist in my document, I would like to add it. Thank you !

Comment: Ok, there is a typo in your query then. Because you query for 'car.type', even though your document is 'cars.type'. Also, your query shouldn't find anything since "wheel.type": "michelin" also returns no results.